# Probability of receiving a fixed bit sequence in a binary symmetric channel

Tags: communication, digital-communications

[image]

What is the probability of receiving `1111` irrespective of what was
transmitted?

\$0.1^4 + 0.9^4 = 0.6562 \$

I am not sure about my answer because I think in my solution I am excluding the probability of getting `1111` as a combination of the two (0 or 1). I only assumed that the `1111` is a result of `0` being transmitted \$0.1^4\$ or `1` \$0.9^4\$.

Can anyone clarify this point to me?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the answer can be derived as follows:

The probability of receiving `1111` is equal to the probability of transmitting a `1` taken to the fourth power.  The probability of transmitting a `1` is equal to the sum of the probability of transmitting a `1` given the input is a `0` plus the probability of transmitting a `1` given the input is a `1`. Based on your information that is equal to:

\$0.4 \cdot 0.1 + 0.6 \cdot 0.9 = 0.04 + 0.54 = 0.58\$

Thus the probability of receiving `1111` is \$0.58^4 = 0.1132\$